# Getting a null value in the check box column while loading Jqxgrid page first time

Tags: jqxgrid

I am getting null value in check box column while onload jqxgrid first time.

```
Column properties:
    { text: ”, type: ‘bool’,datafield: ‘available’, columntype: ‘checkbox’,checked:false, width: 70},

jqxgrid properties:
    width: ’100%’,
    source: transAdapter,
    autoheight: true,
    pageable: true,
    altrows:true,
    editable: true,
    selectionmode: ‘multiplecellsextended’,
```

Here I am not using `threestatecheckbox` property also but still I am getting null value in that column.can you help me how to fix these issue?

Comment: could you fix that problem?

Comment: @Mayrhofer One of my college has answered the question, can you check that out?

Comment: i just solved it myself by setting "filteritems" array with the values i wanted to display in addition to the already set "filtertype" (checkedlist") but anyway thx for your reply

Comment: @Mayrhofer Okay! Can you upvote the answer, he will get the points !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want pass value for that datafield(available field) through json or array as input.
If you pass False as input it will uncheck the checkbox in onload.
If you pass True as input it will  check the checkbox in onload.

This is the way you can fix the issue.